# mysql query with like and group by not using index

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, sql-like

I have a problem with a query not using the right index or any index at all.

### Here is my TABLE CREATE

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
 `data_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `other_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `author_text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `sometext` text NOT NULL,
 `somehash` char(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `longurl` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `published` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `language` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
 `level` enum('-1','0','1','2') CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
 `day` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `processed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`data_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `unique_url` (`other_id`,`somehash`),
 KEY `processed` (`processed`),
 KEY `language` (`day`,`language`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2576573 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

### The QUERY

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS `num` , `data`.`language` AS `language`
FROM `data`
WHERE `data`.`author_text` LIKE '%test%'
AND `data`.`day`
BETWEEN '1364342400'
AND '1372118399'
GROUP BY `data`.`language`
ORDER BY `data`.`language` ASC
```

### An EXPLAIN

```
id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys|key |key_len|ref |rows   |Extra
--|-----------|-----|----|-------------|----|-------|----|-------|--------------------------------------------
1 |SIMPLE     |data |ALL |language     |NULL|NULL   |NULL|2563731|Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: what is your problem?? You don't mention that in your question!

Comment: LIKE '%test%' won't make use of an index

Comment: The query is slow at 2.5M rows. It takes up to 10 seconds with 9.9 sec "Copying To Tmp Table".

Comment: @fthiella I removed the first wildcard but "LIKE 'test%'" does not use the index.

Comment: The like won't use an index. Partly as there is no index on that column and even if there was the leading wildcard will prevent it as @fthiella says. It possibly should use the language key, but that will depend on how much that timestamp range narrows the number of records down by. As a very rough rule of thumb MySQL seems to ignore indexes which don't reduce the numbr of records below ~25%.

Comment: Do you have an index on `author_text` column?